# Why do many papers not have proper PDF metadata?

Tags: publications, publishers

Of course, this varies depending on your field etc., but at least for computer science seems to be true, there’s even [a paper](http://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/file/aumueller2009pdfmeat.pdf) about this problem.

By proper, I mean even basic things like a title (so I don’t have to rename `bla-12345.pdf` to something meaningful by hand) or author. This is missing even in papers that were created with LaTeX and the Hyperref package, like [these](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2882925) [two](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1559911), which make adding this kind of metadata incredibly easy – even the LibreOffice Writer PDF export sets this metadata correctly.

Comment: Where are you obtaining the pdfs from?  "bla-12345.pdf" sounds exactly like the sort of thing you'd download from a website that hosts large numbers of files, which results in "human readable" filenames being inefficient on their end and way too likely to result in collisions.

Comment: Welcom to academia.stackexchange, @Wieland! While I do not have the answer, it might be that others just do not see the need for it and therefore do not bother. I, for instance, never saw this as a problem and never relied on PDF metadata (as opposed to MP3-metadata, for example).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy The ACM links in my question lead to files with similar filenames (they include the name of the first author, but I don't find that particularly useful).

Comment: Weird, it's like the big publishers don't want you to download a massive collection of pdf files, index it and manage it automatically...

Comment: @damian Even if it's not useful for everybody, AFAIU papers in journals/conference proceedings are usually created with a template from the organizer/publisher/..., so just enabling this centrally shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It's 2016 - we have self-driving cars, but think people are not able to use some cheap OCR software to extract the few words in big bold letters at the beginning of documents? That would be a very cheap excuse ;-)

Comment: @Wieland So your question seems to want to decry the lack of nice "human readable" filenames (which, incidentally, have nothing at all to do with a file's metadata), yet you just provided an argument of why this is unnecessary and in many ways counterproductive.  I think Spock would say "The wants of a couple of readers are outweighed by the needs of the organization that organizes, secures, and distributes vast amounts of information to a substantially larger number of people".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Well, yes, considering that filenames are the only thing I can think of that most applications can fall back to if no metadata is included in the PDF files, those are the primary use case for me. I could also generate headings for the org-mode file I use for note taking automatically and extract keywords that make managing multiple files easier, so this is definitely not limited to filenames.

Comment: PDF files have metadata?

Comment: _people are not able to use some cheap OCR software to extract the few words in big bold letters at the beginning of documents?_ — In fact, people have **free** OCR software to extract the few words in big bold letters.  It's called Google Scholar.